# .Netcore alternative for Microsoft.Azure.Management.HDInsight.Job?

Tags: azure-hdinsight, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

I'm working on converting a library from full .NetFramework to .NetCore

I'm looking for a replacement for [Microsoft.Azure.Management.HDInsight.Job](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.HDInsight.Job/), which hasn't been updated in over a year and is not compatible with .NetCore.  I was hoping that the functionality would be rolled up into the much-more-recently-updated and netcore-compatible [Microsoft.Azure.Management.HDInsight](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.HDInsight/3.0.1-preview), but that doesn't appear to be the case.

I'm down to use the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/hdinsight/), but I haven't been able to find the same functionality there.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Commonly, Rest API is a complement of SDK, so could you tell me what the functionality you want, or you give more detail code and description.

Comment: I'm looking to submit jobs to an HDInsight cluster.  I want the functionality of IJobOperations.SubmitHiveJobAsync, IJobOperations.SubmitMapReduceJobAsync,  IJobOperations.SubmitPigJobAsync, and IJobOperations.SubmitSqoopJobAsync.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to install Microsoft.Azure.Management.HDInsight.Job with Package Manager to install some prerelease versions, so that its dependencies would not be conflict with your asp.net core.

I test them, no matter it is preview, it also have the functionality what you want.

Write in Package Manager Console such as:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.HDInsight.Job -Version 1.0.7-preview
```

You could only install the **version <= 1.0.7-preview**. If not, you may could not install it.

For more detail, you could refer to this [article](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.HDInsight.Job).

Answer (score 0):

I found the REST API I was looking for.  It is the WebHCat API, not an Azure API.

MapReduce Job creation: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/WebHCat+Reference+MapReduceJar

Pig Job creation:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/WebHCat+Reference+Pig

Hive Job creation:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/WebHCat+Reference+Hive

Sqoop Job creation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hadoop/apache-hadoop-use-sqoop-curl and https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.3/RESTAPI.html

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully they will release 3.0.0 soon
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/9219